# how i can hide the first \verse number while start counting next verse from 2

Tags: numbering, verse

[image]

the MWE is here;

% SAMPLE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrLSu.jpg

```
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{poemscol}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]

  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}

\setlength{\headwidth}{1.27\textwidth}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\setlength{\headsep}{1em}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}

\clubpenalty10000

\widowpenalty10000

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\versenumcolor{gray}

\newcommand\chapnumcolor{gray}

\renewcommand\paragraph{%

  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%

                {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%

                {-.5em}%set the verse text up and down

                {\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%

\newlength{\biblechapskip}

  \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .3em minus .2em}

\newcounter{biblechapter}

\newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]

\renewcommand\chaptername{Book}

\let\ltx@chapter=\chapter

\let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph


\definecolor{NameBlue}{cmyk}{1,.5,0,0.60}

%\newcommand{\propernoun}[1]{\textcolor{NameBlue}{#1}}%

\newcommand{\propernoun}[1]{\fontfamily{sfdefault}\selectfont{#1}}

%Define Book

\newcommand{\book}[1]{%

  \gdef\currbook{#1}

  \ltx@chapter{#1}}

\newcount\biblechap@svdopt


%Define Chapter

\newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]

  {\biblechap@svdopt=#1

  \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else

    \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi

 \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}

  \refstepcounter{biblechapter}

  \lettrine[lines=3, lhang=-0.23, loversize=-.1, findent=0em]

{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-.1em\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}

  {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}

%Define Verse

\renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%

  \refstepcounter{bibleverse}

  %heading

  \textsuperscript{\sffamily\tiny\textcolor{gray}\thebibleverse}

  \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}

  %\ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else

%   {#1}\hspace{1em}\fi

}%

\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%

  \kern -3pt

  \hrule width \textwidth height 0.3pt

  \kern 2pt

}

\usepackage{mathastext}

%define poem


\title{title}

\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{목록}

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter

\begin{biblechapter} \verse no number

\verse this should have number 2

\section{section}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section}

\verse this should have number 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming that your chapter environment will reset the verse number to 1, you could have the reset value be 2 instead of 1. Then don't use \verse for v. 1 and place it for the first time for v. 2.  The chapter env should then include a \markright ch#:1 to handle v. 1.

Comment: thanks for the response, if you write the code it will be great, as i am getting error for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought, I realized that initializing the verse number to 1 at the beginning of the chapter and just marking the 2nd verse onwards won't work in all cases. For example, in Protestant translations of the Psalms in English, some Psalms have some text *before* verse 1. In those cases you will probably want verse 1 to print.

Here's a verse command (calling it \myverse to avoid a name collision with Latex's built-in \verse). The starred version increments the verse number and performs the \markright, but it does not print. The regular version prints. Either will allow to explicitly set the verse number with an optional parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{biblechapter}
\setcounter{biblechapter}{1}

\newcounter{bibleverse}
\setcounter{bibleverse}{1}

\def\myverse{\@ifstar\@myverse\@@myverse}

% starred version doesn't print
\newcommand*{\@myverse}[1][\value{bibleverse}]{%
  \setcounter{bibleverse}{#1}%
  \markright{{\scshape} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}%
  \refstepcounter{bibleverse}%
}

\newcommand*{\@@myverse}[1][\value{bibleverse}]{%
  \setcounter{bibleverse}{#1}%
  \textsuperscript{\sffamily\tiny\thebibleverse}{\kern 1pt}%
  \markright{{\scshape} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}%
  \refstepcounter{bibleverse}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myverse* The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want.

\myverse He maketh me to lie down in green pastures: he
leadeth me beside the still waters.

\myverse He restoreth my soul: he leadeth me in the paths of
righteousness for his name's sake.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this problem using `poemscol`, using its facilities to number sentences and paragraphs. To do this, issue `\setprosebysentence` in your preamble. Also issue `\suppressfirstparatrue` and `\suppressfirstsentencetrue` (which are new commands in `poemscol` 3.141). In the text, enclose your text in the `pmsection` environment. Begin every paragraph with `\pmpara`. And begin every sentence with `\pmsentence`. Here is a minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry,keyval,ifthen,mparhack}
\usepackage{poemscol}
\raggedbottom
\maketextnotes
\setprosebysentence
\setpmmodulo{1}
\runningsentencenumberstrue
\marginsentencenumbersfalse
\pmsentencebyparatrue
\pmparainmartrue
\pmpararunningtrue
\suppressfirstparatrue
\suppressfirstsentencetrue
\begin{document}

\prosesectiontitle{Job}
\begin{pmsection}
\pmpara
\pmsentence There was a man in the land of Uz, whose name was Job; and that man was blameless and upright, one who feared God, and turned away from evil.\pmsentence There were born to him seven sons and three daughters. \pmsentence He had seven thousand sheep, three thousand camels, five hundred yoke of oxen, and five hundred she-asses, and very many servants; so that this man was the greatest of all the people of the east. \pmsentence His sons used to go and hold a feast in the house of each on his day; and they would send and invite their three sisters to eat and drink with them. \pmsentence And when the days of the feast had run their course, Job would send and sanctify them, and he would rise early in the morning and offer burnt offerings according to the number of them all; for Job said, ``It may be that my sons have sinned, and cursed God in their hearts.'' Thus Job did continually. \pmsentence Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the Lord, and Satan[a] also came among them. \pmsentence The Lord said to Satan, ``Whence have you come?'' Satan answered the Lord, ``From going to and fro on the earth, and from walking up and down on it.'' \pmsentence And the Lord said to Satan, ``Have you considered my servant Job, that there is none like him on the earth, a blameless and upright man, who fears God and turns away from evil?'' \pmsentence Then Satan answered the Lord, ``Does Job fear God for nought? \pmsentence Hast thou not put a hedge about him and his house and all that he has, on every side? Thou hast blessed the work of his hands, and his possessions have increased in the land. \pmsentence But put forth thy hand now, and touch all that he has, and he will curse thee to thy face.'' \pmsentence And the Lord said to Satan, ``Behold, all that he has is in your power; only upon himself do not put forth your hand.'' So Satan went forth from the presence of the Lord.\pmsentence Now there was a day when his sons and daughters were eating and drinking wine in their eldest brother’s house; \pmsentence and there came a messenger to Job, and said, ``The oxen were plowing and the asses feeding beside them; \pmsentence and the Sab\'{e}ans fell upon them and took them, and slew the servants with the edge of the sword; and I alone have escaped to tell you.'' \pmsentence While he was yet speaking, there came another, and said, ``The fire of God fell from heaven and burned up the sheep and the servants, and consumed them; and I alone have escaped to tell you.'' \pmsentence While he was yet speaking, there came another, and said, ``The Chald\'{e}ans formed three companies, and made a raid upon the camels and took them, and slew the servants with the edge of the sword; and I alone have escaped to tell you.'' \pmsentence While he was yet speaking, there came another, and said, ``Your sons and daughters were eating and drinking wine in their eldest brother’s house; \pmsentence and behold, a great wind came across the wilderness, and struck the four corners of the house, and it fell upon the young people, and they are dead; and I alone have escaped to tell you.'' \pmsentence Then Job arose, and rent his robe, and shaved his head, and fell upon the ground, and worshiped. \pmsentence And he said, ``Naked I came from my mother’s womb, and naked shall I return; the Lord gave, and the Lord has taken away; blessed be the name of the Lord.''
\pmsentence In all this Job did not sin or charge God with wrong.

\pmpara
\pmsentence  Again there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves before the Lord, and Satan also came among them to present himself before the Lord.  \pmsentence And the Lord said to Satan,``Whence have you come?''Satan answered the Lord,``From going to and fro on the earth, and from walking up and down on it.''\pmsentence  And the Lord said to Satan,``Have you considered my servant Job, that there is none like him on the earth, a blameless and upright man, who fears God and turns away from evil? He still holds fast his integrity, although you moved me against him, to destroy him without cause.''\pmsentence  Then Satan answered the Lord,``Skin for skin! All that a man has he will give for his life. \pmsentence  But put forth thy hand now, and touch his bone and his flesh, and he will curse thee to thy face.''\pmsentence  And the Lord said to Satan,``Behold, he is in your power; only spare his life.”
\pmsentence  So Satan went forth from the presence of the Lord, and afflicted Job with loathsome sores from the sole of his foot to the crown of his head. \pmsentence  And he took a potsherd with which to scrape himself, and sat among the ashes.\pmsentence  Then his wife said to him,``Do you still hold fast your integrity? Curse God, and die.''\pmsentence  But he said to her,``You speak as one of the foolish women would speak. Shall we receive good at the hand of God, and shall we not receive evil?''In all this Job did not sin with his lips.
\pmsentence  Now when Job’s three friends heard of all this evil that had come upon him, they came each from his own place, El\'{\i}phaz the T\'{e}manite, Bildad the Shuhite, and Zophar the N\'{a}mathite. They made an appointment together to come to condole with him and comfort him. \pmsentence  And when they saw him from afar, they did not recognize him; and they raised their voices and wept; and they rent their robes and sprinkled dust upon their heads toward heaven. \pmsentence  And they sat with him on the ground seven days and seven nights, and no one spoke a word to him, for they saw that his suffering was very great.



\end{pmsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also substitute \bibleverse for \pmsentence and \biblechapter for \pmpara.

Comment: For the special case dedded mentions you can switch off the booleans \suppressfirstparafalse and \suppressfirstsentencefalse, then switch them back on again for the next text.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit! It made my answer much clearer.